# what is difference between weather and climate?

Tags: word-difference

> Weather is the state of the atmosphere, to the degree that it is hot or cold, wet or dry, calm or stormy, clear or cloudy

<sup>([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weather))</sup>

> Climate is the statistics (usually, mean or variability) of weather, usually over a 30-year interval.

<sup>([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Climate))</sup>

still I didn't find any difference?

Comment: You don't see a difference between the status of the atmosphere on a single day compared to the average over three decades?

Comment: The following sentence in your source for the weather quote is: "Weather refers to day-to-day temperature and precipitation activity, whereas climate is the term for the statistics of atmospheric conditions over longer periods of time."

Comment: Reminds me of my 6th standard geography book when I had the exact same question in it.

Answer (score 7):

If I step outside and it rains on me, that's the **weather**.
If I expect frost and snow in winter, a lot of dry heat in summer and a certain distribution of rainfall over the average year, that's the **climate**.

The weather leads me to choosing between a t-shirt or a winter coat today, the local climate makes me buy a winter coat (living in Alaska) or not (living in southern India).

In short, the combination of temperature, wind, precipitation, ... *at one point in time*, e.g. *right now*, that's the weather, climate is the average statistical distribution of these over a year.

Answer (score 1):

The *weather* is what's happening at a given moment (raining, snowing, hot and sunny, etc.)

The *climate* refers to the average or expected weather -- a hot, dry climate; a rainy climate, etc. The climate tells you what the weather will typically be like in a particular season.

Answer (score 1):

Meteorologically, commonly used words with either weather and climate are

> the **current** weather
>   the **general** climate

The weather is something that happens now, climate is the general trends in the weather.

> Global warming creates **climate change** which will effect the **weather**.

An exception to this

> The **climate** in the office was tense today.

meaning the people or situation in the office was tense.

Comment: I've upvoted this, because you've raised some good points and provided some good examples. That said, I'm not sure how much I like your "the climate in the office was tense today" example. If the office is usually tense, the I'd be inclined to say, "The climate in the office is tense." However, if it's generally laid back, then I might say, "The mood in the office was tense today." The word _mood_ seems more analogous to _weather_, while _climate_ applies more to a "prevailing trend" than a one-day anomaly.

Comment: @J.R. Thanks J.R.  I've only heard "climate" used in the shorter term, e.g. "the overall *climate* of the meeting was beneficial" referring to a broader base than a specific point. "Mood" can go both ways, long and short term, and is usually qualified e.g. "the mood in the office is *generally* good", "the mood in the office was buzzing *today*"

Answer (score 0):

Weather is on a day to day basis, like sunny, raining, snowing, cold or warm. 
Climate is the typical weather over a long period of time, usually many years.